# When you create a new Set in Javascript do you iterate?

Tags: javascript

The reason this problem came up was to check if a word contained duplicate letters. The approach I wanted to take was:

```
var word = "will"
var x = new Set(word)

if(x.size == word.length){
    console.log("no duplicates")
}else{
    console.log("duplicates")
}
```

I know when you create a Set the value can only occur once. Trying to determine if this was an efficient approach I'm not sure if when you create a Set if it iterates or does it use some sort of hash table.

Comment: Set objects are collections of ECMAScript language values. A distinct value may only occur once as an element of a Set's collection. Distinct values are discriminated using the [SameValueZero](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) comparison algorithm. [source](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-set-objects)

Comment: What is it your wanting?.  As the above is not going to check for duplicate `letters`,   `efficient approach` if correctly used, yes.

Comment: Are you just asking if putting `word` in a Set causes `word` to be iterated?

Comment: If you was wanting to check for duplicates using a set, something like -> `var hasDups = (s) => new Set(s.split('')).size !== s.length;`    and then `hasDups('hello');` would be true, and `hasDups('dog')` would be false.

Comment: It won't tell you what letters were duplicates, but it will tell you if there were any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about performance, I would recommend using jsPerf and comparing any other ways of doing this that you may have already think about.

Try to use your specific scenario since it may depend on the engine that is running the code and the actual scenario that is running.

take this as an example
https://jsperf.com/dedupe-a-list

Comment: yes this seems to answer my question. I wasn't sure if it would have been easier for me to just make a filter method. I curious what the most efficient approach would have been. Thank you